# How can I get a file path from project root

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my full file path
`/Users/UserName/project/first_level/second/somename/my_file.py`

I import the file and then want to get it path from relative to project(for me the root is `project`)

I need to get the `first_level/second/somename/my_file.py`
When I do `my_file.__file__` I get the full path

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.relpath`

Let's say that you have structure

```
project
│   main.py
|
└───fist_level
│   │   
|   |____second_level
|   |    my_file.py
|   ...
```

If you run main.py

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

import fist_level.second_level.my_file

# will print relative path to my_file.py file from main.py
print(os.path.relpath(my_file.__file__, Path(__file__).parent))
```

If you want to get the relative path to your root project from another file you will need to set somewhere
`ROOT_DIR` and then run `print(os.path.relpath(my_file.__file__, ROOT_DIR))`

(Very similar in Django in settings.py it usually sets

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: waisted on it about 2 hours!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `/Users/UserName/project` will be always the same you can split the path by `\` and then join from the third element in the list to the end:

```
>>> path_to_file = "/Users/UserName/project/first_level/second/somename/my_file.py"
>>> ("/").join(path_to_file.split("/")[3:])
'project/first_level/second/somename/my_file.py'
```

If you don't know where it will be located, you can find project on the splited list and then join:

```
>>> path_split = path_to_file.split("/")
>>> ("/").join(path_split[path_split.index("project")+1:])
'first_level/second/somename/my_file.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

From `my_file.py` one can use `relpath()`.

**my_file.py**

```py
import os
print(os.path.relpath(__file__, os.curdir))
```

Should give you :

```
first_level/second/somename/my_file.py
```

When imported